# How to hide some pages from Drawer Navigation but still be able to navigate to them - React Native?

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

### I want to hide some pages from the Drawer

I want to hide some pages from the Drawer (for example hide the SignUpPage and SuccessPage), how can I do it ?
i also tried to make an anonymous  function in the DrawerLabel [ ()=> null ] but it is still not a good solution because even tho it shows me an empty label, yet when i click on it , it navigates me to the page that i wanted to hide.

Please help
and thanks for all the helpers :)

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer'; 
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function DrawerNavigator() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="WelcomePage">
     
     //...all the pages
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="HomePage"
        component={HomePage}
        options={{ drawerLabel: 'Home Page' }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="SignUpPage"
        component={SignUpPage}
        options={{ drawerLabel: 'SignUp Page' }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="SuccessPage"
        component={SuccessPage}
        options={{ drawerLabel: 'SuccessPage' }}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    < NavigationContainer >
     

      <DrawerNavigator>

        <Stack.Navigator initialRouterName="WelcomePage">
          <Stack.Screen name="WelcomePage" component={WelcomePage} />
          >
          <Stack.Screen name="SuccessPage" component={SuccessPage} />
          <Stack.Screen name="HomePage" component={HomePage} />

        </Stack.Navigator>

      </DrawerNavigator>
    </NavigationContainer >
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have differents options
I guess you want to hide that options when your user is signed or not. With v5 you can do the code below. The another option is the same but playing with custom content that is a bit complex also I give you the docs if you want the complex solution https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator.
DrawerNavigator

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function DrawerNavigator() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="WelcomePage">
     
     //...all the pages
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="HomePage"
        component={HomePage}
        options={{ drawerLabel: 'Home Page' }}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

AuthNavigator

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator<AuthParamList>();
export const AuthNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator headerMode='none'>
            <Stack.Screen name='SignUpPage' component={SignUpPage}></Stack.Screen>
            <Stack.Screen name='SuccessPage' component={SuccessPage}></Stack.Screen>
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
};
```

IsAuthScreen, I use firebase + redux so here you need to put your login logic

```
const IsAuth: React.FC<RoutesProps> = (props) => {
    const { eva, ...rest } = props;
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const onAuthStateChanged = (currentUser: any) => {
        console.log("onAuthStateChanged -> currentUser", currentUser)
        if (!currentUser) {
            dispatch(new authActions.DidTryLogin());
        } else {
            if (!currentUser.emailVerified) {
                dispatch(new authActions.DidTryLogin());
            } else {
                dispatch(new authActions.SigninSuccess(currentUser));
                dispatch(new settingsActions.GetProfile(currentUser.uid));
            }
        }
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        
        const subscriber = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);

        return () => {
            subscriber();
        }; // unsubscribe on unmount
    }, [dispatch]);

    return (<View >
        <LoadingIndicator size='large' /> // Here put a loading component
    </View>);
};
```

App component, I use redux for check if my user is logged so here you need to put your own logic

```
const isAuth = useSelector(selectAuthUser);
const didTryAutoLogin = useSelector(selectAuthDidTryLogin);
return (
<NavigationContainer>
            {isAuth && <DrawerNavigator />}
            {!isAuth && didTryAutoLogin && && <AuthNavigator />}
            {!isAuth && !didTryAutoLogin && <IsAuthScreen />}
        </NavigationContainer>);
```

So when you logout you don't need to navigate to SignInScreen (this will be a problem if you think about it because if you want to do that you can back to protected screens with the back button or gesture). You only need to update the state and the correct navigator will be in place and you can put the default screen to show. You can achieve this with redux or react context.

Comment: First thanks for your intention of trying to help me, 
it solves the problem of hiding it from the drawer *BUT* it "cancels" the hidden screens existence.
For example lets say that your way worked, and i successfully got to hide the "SignUpPage", now when i want to navigate normally to the SignUpPage, i get an error says "The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name": "SignUpPage"} was not handled by any navigator.
"Do you have a screen named 'SignUpPage'?"

Comment: Let me confirm me what u want. You really want to be in the drawer signup and success page ? if not you should declarate outside of the DrawerNavigator. Confirm it and I can give u an example

Comment: i just want to see the "WelcomePage" and the "HomePage" in the Drawer,
all of the rest of the pages (which are - SuccessPage, SIgnUpPage, LoginPage) i don't want to see them in the Drawer list.
The main idea is, when i login , i enter my HomePage and there is a bar Icon that i click on it and it shows me my drawer ( with the ONLY pages that i want to see ).

thanks Anthony. and sorry for confusing you :)

Comment: I did an edit, hope it helps its a bit complex so think about it